# How to verify a directory is a SVN repository

Tags: svn

In the process of setting up a backup 'script' for my SVN directories ( *ON THE SERVER* - not my local working directories) via svnadmin using a GUI or DND to add to the backup list I would like to check, as a safety feature, that each of the selected directories is in fact a proper SVN directory.

I have looked at my existing directory structure and find it has the following sub-directories: 
conf, db, hooks, locks 
as well as the files format & README.txt

All SVN repos & directories are presently created/handled by the current version 1.7.10 of TortoiseSVN.

Any ideas or comments on how checking for this specific structure is a good way to accept only SVN directories and reject all others?

TIA

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to create a backup from the file structure? Why not use the recommended way and just create a dump for backup?

Comment: I am not backing up the structure - at least not directly. I want to verify that the directory is actually a SVN repo and not just any old directory!!

Comment: @user999713 - SVN-repo is the full tree under any `SVNParentPath` child

Comment: @user999713 Using `svnadmin dump` (on your server) would give you only active repositories. Is your actual problem that you do not have reliable information which repostories are actively served?

Comment: @Filburt The problem is that the user of the backup script might select a directory which is _not_ a part of the SVN repo tree. I want to be able to give the user reasonably intelligent feedback as to why the directory was/is being rejected (preferred) or why backup failed.

Answer (score 6):

Just came across this same problem.
The commands svnlook info and svnlook youngest (and probably others as well) give an exit code of 0 or 1 depending on whether the supplied directory is a subversion repository or not.
This applies to SVN repos and not 'working copy' of them as user999713 claims.
So the following bash script shows 0 when *directory* is a SVN repo and 1 if not.

```
svnlook info directory > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `svn info %directory%`?  It returns an exit code of != 0 if the directory is not revisioned by subversion and it's independant of your WC structure.  Plus, it works only on your local side, no connection to the repo necessary.

Comment: This also checks if the directory is a 'working copy" - Please read my 'edited' question.

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool `svn` gives you the ability to do `svn ls` of a particular file or directory. This will return a zero if the directory exists and a non-zero (a `1`) if the directory doesn't exist. You could use this in your program.

```
echo -n "What directory?" 
read directory
if svn ls $REPO/$directory > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Directory $directory exists in $REPO"
else
    echo "ERROR: Directory $directory does not exist in $REPO"
fi
```

If this is taking place on the server, you can do something similar with `svnlook tree`. This will be faster than using `svn ls`.

By the way, you realize when you back up in Subversion, the repository directory structure is very, very different from the layout of the working directory. To backup Subversion, it's recommended that you use `svnadmin dump` or `svnadmin hotcopy`. You could write a script to get to track the last revision of Subversion that was backed up, and then only do a `svnadmin dump` of the newer revisions. That way, the backup doesn't take that long, and you can still reconstruct your repository from all the dumps.

Comment: `if svn ls $REPO/$directory` is just **terrible bad and wrong** - I have Ns directories `trunk` form Ns *different repos*